# How can i count time on long-pressed button using UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement

How can I count time on how long the button is pressed using UILongPressGestureRecognizer; I am looking to print the long-Pressed count time in the displayLabel.text

I've tried most possible way.

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonPressed: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!

var buttonPressedCount : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let longPressObj = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressButton))
    longPressObj.minimumPressDuration = 2
    longPressObj.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressObj)


    // below statement is not a right one but i tried many possiblity including this one.
    if longPressObj.minimumPressDuration == TimeInterval(2) {
        displayLabel.text = "Longpressed for 2 seconds"
    } else if longPressObj.minimumPressDuration == TimeInterval(3) {
        displayLabel.text = "3"
    } else if longPressObj.minimumPressDuration == TimeInterval(3) {
        displayLabel.text = "4"
    }


}
 @IBAction func longPressButton() {

    displayLabel.text = "Button pressed for \(buttonPressedCount)"
}
```

I want to display time of the long-Pressed **NOT BUTTON CLICKED.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppr0W.png)

Thank you in advance!

EDITS:- 
1.  I just want to show the Running duration while the user is performed Long-Press. I would really appreciate the real-time count in the
2. Also is it will be helpful to show the total duration after stop pressing.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppr0W.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to show a running duration while the user is performing the long press or do you want to show the total duration after the user stops pressing?

Comment: @rmaddy : Sorry ! my bad. I just want to show the Running duration while the user is performed Long-Press. I would really appreciate the real-time count in the displayLabel

Comment: [Edit] your question with your clarifications instead of posting details in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a long press gesture recognizer, why not attach button actions to the `touchDownInside` event and the `touchUpInside` and `touchUpOutside` events on your button. your touchDownInside code can start your timer, which would update the label. The `touchUpInside`/`touchUpOutside` action would stop the timer.

Comment: Sure, Thanks @Duncan

Answer (score 2):

Your target function should include sender, then you can get the state of the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.

Here is the [Apple official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilongpressgesturerecognizer).

First save the gesture begin time, then you can use the current time to subtract the begin pressed time to get the duration in state `.ended` (or/and `.cancelled`,  `.failed`).

Sample code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var touchBeginTime: Double = 0
    var touchCountTimer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let longPressObj = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressButton(sender:)))
        longPressObj.minimumPressDuration = 2
        longPressObj.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(longPressObj)
    }

    @IBAction func longPressButton(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        switch sender.state {
            case .began:
                touchCountTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
                    print("User pressing \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - self.touchBeginTime) sec.")
                })
                touchBeginTime = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
                break;

            case .changed:
                //print("Long pressed changed \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - touchBeginTime)")
                break;

            case .ended, .cancelled, .failed:
                touchCountTimer?.invalidate()
                print("User pressed total \(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - touchBeginTime) sec.")
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use a date (startDate) and get the timeIntervalSinceNow property? If you want a positive result you can use `Date().timeIntervalSince(startDate)`

Comment: This solution only works if the user moves their finger during the long press. The `.changed` state is only called if the user moves their finger during the long press. So if the user starts the long press, holds very still for 10 seconds (for example), and then lifts their finger, this code only shows the start and end.

Comment: @LeoDabus Sure it can be, but timeIntervalSince1970 is a double, if you want to save the Date directly, it should be an object and would retain more memory. just depends on you.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, if need a real-time count it should add a timer.

Comment: @SerKo A real-time count is needed. It's in the question.

Comment: @rmaddy sure, added.

Comment: @SerKo a date uses the same amount o bytes as an Int or Double

Comment: Thanks alot @SerKo

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to show the running duration while the long press is being performed, you need to use a timer.

Start the timer when the long press reaches the `.began` state and stop (invalidate) the timer when the long press reaches the `.ended` or `.canceled` state.

Your time should repeat every second and update the label based on the difference between the current date and the date the long press began.

Comment: Sorry, not very clear with your answer, I am a starter. I tried to follow your answer but not sure when how to give a longPress began state or .ended state.

Comment: @KRS change your method signature declaration to `func longPressButton(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {` and just `switch gesture.state { case .began: print("began") case .ended: print("ended")}`

Comment: @LeoDabus - that was helpful and great clarification.